# Windows 10 taskbar settings greyed out

Tags: windows-10

If I right click on my taskbar I am greeted with a greyed out "Taskbar Settings" and "Lock the Taskbar"

If I go to the personalization control panel for the Taskbar, all options are greyed out.

I have created a new local admin user, and the options are greyed out for that user also.

I didn't do anything to make this happen.  I have reverted to the default windows 10 theme.  Following the instructions at [tenforums.com](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105189-enable-disable-taskbar-settings-windows-10-a.html) I have modified the group policy and registry. No joy.

Can someone help?

Comment: Here's your solution: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/105189-enable-disable-taskbar-settings-windows-10-a.html  If group policy editor does not work, consider modifying the registry as described

Comment: Hi, I did that prior to posting here.  Nothing has helped.

Comment: Is your computer connected to a domain?

Comment: Do you have an installation of office 365 which has a non-personal license, e.g. a commercial license, belongs to an organization or to a specific domain?

Comment: Also, if you have tried the registry fix, it would be appropriate to mention that in your question. Consider editing your question in that way.